# React JS Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having an error in line `user.name = name,`

look this function:

```
  SaveEdit = (id, name, email, phone) => {
    const newData = this.state.data.map( user => {
      if ( user.id === id ) {
        user.name = name,
        user.email = email,
        user.phone = phone
      }
      return user;
    });
    this.setState({ data: newData });
  }
```

this is the error: `Line 49:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`
so Line 49:9: is `user.name = name,`

so, I'm trying to create a function to edit in this function `SaveEdit` I saved it

what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: use semicolon `;` instead of comma `,`

Comment: as an aside, you're directly mutating state here, which is likely to lead to problems. You should replace those three assignments with something like `return { ...user, name, email, phone };`